# Сложный запрос на MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть две таблицы, product и image.

Сейчас есть такой запрос который корректно работает.

```
if(isset($price['min']))
            $this->db->where('price >=',$price['min']);
        if(isset($price['max']))
            $this->db->where('price <=',$price['max']);
        $this->db->order_by($sort);
        $this->db->where('id_subcategory',$scID);
        if(is_array(@$IDs))
            $this->db->where_in('id',$IDs);
        $this->db->where('id_subcategory',$scID);
        $this->db->where('count !=',0);
        if(!empty($ll))
            $this->db->limit($ll,$page*$ll);
        $query = $this->db->get('tm_product');
        $res['products']= $query->result();

        return $res;
```

Как дописать запрос что бы он проверял, есть ли изображение продукта в таблице image. Т.Е. нужно тупо получать товары с фото.

Comment: В вашем коде нет ни какой `mysql` даже приблизительно.

Comment: *нужно тупо получать товары с фото* Внутреннее, а не левое, связывание таблицы фотографий в источнике данных запроса. Или любое условие с использованием любого поля этой таблицы в секции отбора.

Comment: Вообще если таблица уже приджойнена достаточно написать например $this->db->where('image is not null'); image это поле по которому можно понять загружена ли картинка. (может там надо будет !=0 например тм по данным надо смотреть) Если вообще всегда надо только с картинками можно поправить джойн с LEFT на INNER как писали выше в комменте.